# Runtime.getRuntime.exec()

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, telnet, runtime.exec

I am trying to run this command-

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("telnet " + serverIP);
```

and nothing happens. I am not able to figure out why!

Comment: Try seeing what the output is with `Process p = Runtime....; InputStream stdOut = p.getInputStream();`

Comment: I don't get to see anything in the output console

Comment: @Kit Ho: i expected it to work the way it would in the terminal.Doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

a) Avoid telnet, if possible, because it is so unsecure!

b) You have to pass a program name, which is "telnet", not "telnet ", and add parameters in an array "telnet", "IP", ... .

c) You have to use the whole path to telnet, because Java doesn't evaluate the PATH.

Here is a more complete overview of [pitfalls with Runtime.getRuntime ().exec](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to "user unknown"s answer:

Telnet is not shiped with [Windows Vista](http://www.arsgeek.com/2007/03/20/enable-telnet-in-windows-vista/) and [Windows Se7en](http://www.fettesps.com/windows-7-enable-telnet/). You'll have to install it manually.

Also, since telnet communicates over TCP, you should use [`Sockets`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) to do so in your program.

Comment: Forgot to mention.. I'm using linux